# jQuery Validation: How can I manually trigger error inside rule?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have these codes:

```
rules: {
    shop_name: {
        minlength: 4,
        remote: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: window.location.origin + '/api/shop/',
            success: function (data) { console.log(typeof data); console.log(data); }
        },
        required: true
    }
}
```

The `remote` rule expect the returned value to be `echo "true"` or `echo "false"`. However, my API returned JSON with (for example in `success:`) `data.exist == true` for valid and `data.exist == false` for invalid value.

How can I have something like this, perhaps:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (!data.exist) {
        // Trigger error here
    }
    else {
        // Remove error here
    }
}
```

Comment: you may try this code  `echo json_encode($data['exist']=true)` in your php file

Comment: Don't have access to backend

Comment: use `console.log(typeof data);` to identify the error and handle it.

Comment: Rather than trying to trigger the error, could you use `dataFilter` to manipulate the returned value into the right format?

Comment: What error? There is no error.

Comment: So something like: `dataFilter: function (data) { if (data.includes('true')) return 'true' else return 'false'; }`

Comment: If you don’t have access to back end, then you can’t fix anything.  Read the docs: the response from the back end must be JSON encoded.

Comment: My response is JSON. But from `remote:` the return should be string "true" or "false", which is very opinionated.

Comment: "If you don’t have access to back end, then you can’t fix anything. Read the docs: the response from the back end must be JSON encoded." jQuery is a front-end library. It must not care what my back-end are.

Comment: Just come back to my workplace, the solution @theduck gave me is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to format the data before sending it into success

```
rules: {
        shop_name: {
            minlength: 4,
            remote: {
                type: 'POST',
                url: window.location.origin + '/api/shop/',
                dataFilter: function (data) {
                    result = $.parseJSON(data);
                    return result.exist;
                },
            },
            required: true
        }
    },
```